# how to take data in mysql database with using php web service

Tags: php, mysql, web, service

I just start to use php webservice.I want to take all data in 'urun' table just sending 'id' Here is my code and i dont know how to solve it.

```
if($_GET["function"] == "getUrun"){

    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] != ""){
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $kategoriid =$_GET["kategoriid"];
        $urunadi =$_GET["urunadi"];
        $urunfiyati =$_GET["urunfiyati"];
        $aciklama =$_GET["aciklama"];
        $where="";
        $where = "id='".$id."' AND kategoriid='".$kategoriid."' AND urunadi='".$urunadi."' AND urunfiyati='".$urunfiyati."' AND aciklama='".$aciklama."'";
        $result  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urun WHERE ".$where."");
        $rows = array();
        if($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $rows[] = $result;
                $data = json_encode($rows);

                echo "{ \"status\":\"OK\", \"getUrun\": ".$data." }";

            }else{
            echo "{ \"status\":\"ERR: Something wrong hepsi\"}";}
    }else{
        echo "{ \"status\":\"ERR: Something wrongs hepsi\"}";}
}
```

Comment: Does your query return more than one row? If so, you need a loop to get all the rows. You should use `json_encode` when the loop is done, to encode the entire result, not each time through the loop.

Comment: Yes,my query return more than one row but as i said i just start to use php.Could you please send show me how to write true loop?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if ($result) {
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'getUrun' => $rows));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERR: Something wrong hepsi'));
}
```

You need to get all the results in an array, and then encode the whole thing. You should also use `json_encode` for the containing object, don't try to create JSON by hand.